# Is $I \times I$ a $2$-manifold in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds

I am using the following definition of
**k-manifold in** $\mathbb{R}^n:$
[image]

The question is :
Let $I=[0,1], $is $I \times I$ a 2-manifold in $\mathbb{R}^2$? I have been searching for this problem, and I found the answer is negative because $I^2$ has the "corner" points. But I don't understand why is that true. Anyone can give a rigorous answer to this problem?

Comment: What is the image of the coordinate patch containing the corner? I don't see how it would be an open set in $\mathbb{H}^2$.

Comment: Hello :) If $I$ is an open intervall, then $I\times I$ is a manifold.

Comment: @Daniel You're right. I have edited my question.

Comment: @Daniel Can you give a rigorous answer to this problem?

Comment: @Jochen You are right ? How to prove there is no coordinate patch about the corner points ?

Comment: If $I=[0,1],$ then it isn’t true, and the problems isn’t just the corners, but any point on the edge. Whatever $I$ is, you should tell us in the question.

Comment: I will think about a way to formulate why it cannot be a manifold but if $I$ is a closed interval, then $I \times I$ is a differentiable manifold with corners. These are kind of explained in Lee's Smooth Manifolds page 415.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I just edited my question. $I$ is [0,1]

Comment: $I\times I$ is what is generally called a "manifold with corners". In doesn't fit to the given definition of a manifold (what in other textbooks this definition is for manifolds without boundary)

Comment: I assume $H^k:=\mathbb R_{\geq 0}\times \mathbb R $ to be the halfspace. Then it is well known, that the boundary of an d-dim manifold (with boundary) itself is a d-1-manifold (without boundary). In that context the lines of the square  are no (differentiable) 1-dim, because of the corners (a smooth map or curve do not have a kink). So it can't be a 2-dim manifold with boundary.

Comment: I think there’s been a bit of confusion here. Often what we call a “manifold” means a “smooth manifold without boundary”. The definition of a manifold here is for a $C^r$-manifold with or without boundary.

Comment: Since $I \times I $ is a $C^0$-manifold with boundary according to this definition it is a manifold

Comment: @Salfalur Can you give the "rigorous" (not visualization) proof that a smooth map or curve do not have a kink? I can visualize it is true, I feel unsatisfied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

If $M$ is a manifold (with boundary) of dimension $\ge 2$, then for every $p$ in $M$ there exists a smooth map $\gamma \colon (-1,1) \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\gamma ((-1,1)) \subset M$, $\gamma(0) = p$, and $\gamma'(0) \ne 0$.

Now show that you cannot have such a map for $M=[0,1]\times [0,1]$, and $p=(0,0)$ (  $\gamma$ will not stay in $I\times I$ around $0$, due to the condition  $\gamma'(0) \ne 0$).

$\bf{Added:}$ Consider a smooth map $\gamma =(\gamma_1, \gamma_2) \colon (-1,1)\to I\times I$, $\gamma(0) = (0,0)$. Since $0$ is a minimum point for both $\gamma_1$, and $\gamma_2$, we have $\gamma_1'(0)=\gamma_2'(0)=0$.

In a similar way we can show that a cube is not a manifold with boundary around any point on an edge. For if $\gamma \colon (-1,1) \to I^3$, $\gamma(0) = p=(0,0, z)$, then again $\gamma_1'(0)=\gamma_2'(0) = 0$, so the vector $\gamma'(0)$ should be along the edge on which $p$ is situated. But for any point $p$ on a $3$-dim manifold with boundary, the possible tangents to paths $\gamma$ with values in $M$ at the point $p$ has dimension at least $2$.

Comment: Hi, can you give me the "rigorous"  proof that $\gamma '(0)$ must be 0 in this case? I can visualize geometrically it because $p$ is a corner point, the tangent line at this point does not exist. But I feel unsatisfied with this visualization. Can you give me a more "rigorous" one?

Comment: @Huy Nguyen: Added some details.